# How to use a converter properly in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have settings for a list of buttons that show recent project file paths at the start up of the application. At this moment in time, file paths that still exist are still clickable, and file paths that are not found are not clickable. However, I want to modify the existing code such that nonexistent files paths are disguishable and have a different background color. How would I do this elegantly?

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="OpenProjectButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToCommandConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipDescription}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonWrapper" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                            <Image Source="{Binding LargeImageUrl}" Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Name="LabelText" Text="{Binding Label}"
                                               Foreground="{StaticResource SelectedForeground}"
                                               FontSize="13" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipDescription}"
                                               Foreground="#616161"
                                               FontSize="11" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonWrapper" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

I'm assuming I want to do a binding/conversion ilke one of the first few Setters, but I'm still not sure how. And this is what I have so far in my conversion class:

```
class CommandEnabledToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public String Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool) value) //if command.Enabled is true
        {
            return "Gray";
        }
        else
        {
            return "LightGray";
        }
    }

    public bool ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.Equals("Gray")) //if command.Enabled is true
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your formatting, question style - and you have at least thought about a possibility of a solution. Keep it up! :)

Comment: Did you try running this yet? I may be misunderstanding your question, but that converter looks fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm don't now how to incorporate the converter into my XAML code such that it'll change the background colors accordingly.

Comment: Also, I'm using Chrome as my browser. Is there any reason why I can't tag anyone in my posts?

Comment: you need to edit it first

Comment: Editing doesn't always work for me either. :/

Comment: Could you not use Command.CanExecute?

Comment: I can't bind to that in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the brushes instead of strings:

```
class CommandEnabledToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public String Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool) value) //if command.Enabled is true
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        }
    }

    public bool ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

}

The strings you normally use in XAML are implicitly converted to brushes, but for a converter this doesn't happen

Comment: Oh, ok! I can try that. However, I'm not sure how to include the converter into my XAML code. I'm learning WPF for the first time, and I'm modifying code that isn't written by myself. Do you have any suggestions for how to include the converter into XAML code based on my conditions?

Comment: do it in the same way as you did for `ObjectToCommandConverter`

Comment: So, something like this? <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource CommandEnabledToBackgroundConverter}}" /> This might be a slightly vague question, but how do I know if that is the right binding? I have an object that has an attribute Enabled and an object Command. The Command object also has an Enabled attribute. I want it to bind to Command.Enabled.

Comment: This is my updated version: <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource CommandEnabledToBackgroundConverter}}" />. It looks more like it'll work, but somehow, the entire value is underlined because the function can't be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a trigger, Your converter is correct, but there is no need to use one in this case.

```
<Trigger Property=Enabled Value=True>
  <Trigger.Setters>
    <Setter Property=Background Value=Gray />
  </Trigger.Setters>
</Trigger>
```

Then just set the default background color to LightGray.

Comment: Thanks! But I have already tried that. The reason why this doesn't work is because I have an object that has several attributes, which Enabled is one of them. It also has an object called Command that contains another Enabled attribute. I need Command.Enabled to trigger the background change. I'm not able to modify those existing classes either, which is why I need a converter. And by calling Enabled, it is the wrong attribute I want as the condition. @pquest